# Seeking an index for the Mishnah Berurah

Tags: product-recommendation, mishnah-berurah

Can anyone tell me where I might find an index to help me find a topic in Mishna Berura (preferably in English)?

Comment: An index of what? Word usage? Topics? You've only used one sentence. Surely there is more you can say to describe what you seek.

Comment: @DoubleAA  I was using the term index as it is usually used: "an alphabetical list of persons, places, subjects, etc, mentioned in the text of a printed work, usually at the back, and indicating where in the work they are referred to" (http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/index).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an index called Yad Yisrael

http://seforimsets.com/index.php?route=product/product&product_id=555

Answer (score 3):

Dirshu has an excellent Hebrew index on all 6 volumes of Mishna Brura, in one volume covering 6,000 categories and 30,000 sub-categories over 600 pages. You can see sample pages [here](https://www.dirshu.co.il/product/%D7%99%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%AA-%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%AA-%D7%97%D7%93%D7%A9%D7%94-%D7%A2%D7%9C-%D7%9E%D7%93%D7%A3-%D7%94%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%9D-%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%A4%D7%AA/). Although it is in Hebrew there are a few dozen pages in English at the end with words translated from modern Hebrew.

See a background article on the publication of this volume [here](https://www.thelakewoodscoop.com/news/2021/02/historic-release-of-dirshu-sefer-hamafteiach-a-groundbreaking-index-on-the-entire-mishnah-berurah.html).

Sold online in the US [here](https://www.israelbookshoppublications.com/store/pc/Sefer-Hamafte-ach-Dirshu-Mishnah-Berurah-8p3620.htm) and [there](https://www.greenfieldjudaica.com/sefer-hamafte-ach-dirshu-mishnah-berurah-LA203.html) for instance.